# how to get all attributes of node in certain namespace xml javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I have a node from an xml document. It has several attributes on it from multiple namespaces. I want to find all the attributes from the fo namespace. How can this be done? e.g. from the following I would want to get all of the attributes starting in fo:

```
<thingy fo:line-height="200%" fo:blah="blah" gh:sdf="sdfdfer">
blah
</thingy>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var tag = document.getElementsByTagName('thingy')[0];
var attr = tag.attributes;
for(var i=0;i<attr.length;i++)
{
    if(attr.item(i).nodeName.search('fo:') == 0)
    {
        alert(attr.item(i).nodeName);
        alert(attr.item(i).nodeValue);
    }
}
```

[Working JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DqXPB/)